# How to parallelize for loop in OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, openmp

This is my program which calculates sum of 10000 element which is assign to 1. The sum should be 5000 for 1st thread and 5000 for other but for every run it is giving different output

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int i,sum1=0,sum2=0,a[10000],sum_final=0;
for(i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    a[i]=1;
}
#pragma omp parallel
{
    if(omp_get_thread_num()==0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<5000;i++)
        {
            sum1+=a[i];
        }
        printf("Sum1 is %d\n",sum1);
    }
    if(omp_get_thread_num()==1)
    {
        for(i=5000;i<10000;i++)
        {
            sum2+=a[i];
        }
        printf("Sum2 is %d\n",sum2);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop counter should be private. I think you should try

```
#pragma omp parallel private(i)
```